# HRESULT: 0xC0048021 in 64 bit mode

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, ssis

Please see the fragment of code below:

```
Dim fuzzyLookup As IDTSComponentMetaData100 = pipeline.ComponentMetaDataCollection.[New]()
        fuzzyLookup.ComponentClassID = "{5056651F-F227-4978-94DF-53CDF9E8CCB6}"
        Dim destDesignTimeComponentFuzzy As IDTSDesigntimeComponent100 = fuzzyLookup.Instantiate()
        destDesignTimeComponentFuzzy.ProvideComponentProperties() 'line 4
```

I have imported the following namespaces:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
```

I have added the following references:

```
Microsoft.SQLServer.dtspipelinewrap.dll
Microsoft.SQLServer.dtsruntimewrap.dll
Microsoft.SQLServer.manageddts.dll
```

When I add 32 Bit references the entire code runs, however nothing happens i.e. package.execute does nothing - the fuzzy lookup does not work (because of this I believe: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/634516)

Therefore I have tried adding 64 bit references to the 3 DLLs above.  Then I get an exception on line 4 of the code:  HRESULT: 0xC0048021.  Why do I get this exception in 64 bit mode?

The research I have done suggests that the component class id is wrong.  Is there a different component class id for 64 bit fuzzy lookup?

**Update 07/10/15**

I have run the code below:

```
Public Shared Sub LoopComponents()
        Dim fileName As String = "C:\Development\ProgrammaticLookup\64Bit.txt"
        Dim application As New Application()
        Dim componentInfos As PipelineComponentInfos = application.PipelineComponentInfos
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each componentInfo As PipelineComponentInfo In componentInfos
            i = i + 1


            Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
                Using sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
                    sw.WriteLine(componentInfo.Name + vbTab + componentInfo.CreationName)
                End Using
            End Using
        Next
        Console.Read()
    End Sub
```

When I run the code above in 32 bit mode, there are 42 entries added to the log file, including: Fuzzy Lookup   DTSTransform.BestMatch.2

When I run the code in 64 bit mode, there are just 11 entries added to the log file.  Fuzzy Lookup is not one of the entries.  Why are there missing components in 64 bit mode?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server 2012 or later?  If so you might be using DTSX2, and it looks like Fuzzy Lookup has a Class ID of `{E4A5F949-EC93-45AB-8B36-B52936257EC2}`, according to [this document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/7/5/175A7833-6F75-418D-8800-86D44D1D712D/[MS-DTSX2].pdf) - page 258.

For an overview of differences in DTSX and DTSX2, [check here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg617124(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Thanks.  I have added an update to the question.  Could you take a look? Fuzzy Lookup is missing in 64 bit mode.